# Have to set module when using view from cocoapod

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I'm currently trying to create a library by using cocoapods for the first time. It mainly exists out of custom views.

However in order for it to work I need to enter the module name after I set the custom class to the UIView.

for instance this doesn't work:
[image]

While this does work:
[image]

I doubt that it is supposed to work like this. Shouldn't it set the module automatically?

If so how do you make sure this happens?
What am I doing wrong exactly.

The code for it is available [here](https://github.com/MaikoHermans/MHWalkthrough)

**EDIT**
I created a test project in order to test it.
I installed my pod by entering this into my `Podfile`

```
pod 'MHWalkthrough', :path => '~/Path/To/Folder/Containing/My/Pod'
```

Comment: did you open the workspace after installing the pods? and are you sure that the project is included?

Comment: yeah I did and the project is included. Because it works but the only thing is that I explicitly have to set the module.